# Getting template syntax error while trying to parse a dictionary in my template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

Ok here is the code of my view.

```
def customers_to_be_called(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.filter(call=True)
    list_of_customers = []
    for cust in customers:
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(customer = cust)
        customer_date = {}
        customer_data['customer'] = cust
        customer_date['jobs'] = jobs
        list_of_customers.append(customer_data)

    return render(request, 'repairs/customers_to_be_called.html',
           {'list_of_customers' : list_of_customers,
    })
```

and here is the template that is gonna be rendered

```
<div>
{% for customer in list_of_customers %}
    <h2> {{customer['customer'].name}} </h2>
    <ul>
    {% for job in customer['jobs'] %}
        <li> {{job.product}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

But When I send a request to this page I get the following error.
[image: Error]

I don't know why it isn't parsing customer in the template while there is data in it..??

Comment: The error tells you all you need to know: that is not valid template syntax. You should read the documentation.

Comment: Oh Sorry I am very new to Django.. I thought I'd work the same way as It does in the python shell..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to dict item do `customer.jobs` not `customer['jobs']`

So your for loop becomes

```
{% for customer in list_of_customers %}
    <h2> {{customer.customer.name}} </h2>
    <ul>
    {% for job in customer.jobs %}
        <li> {{job.product}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```